# Why Profit Target is not activated?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code, and I am trying when I have a trade signal to sell at a specific price or a specific stop loss.

But Trandingview always sells at 1.3% up and not at 4%, do you have any idea why this is happening?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © mpempi

//@version=5

strategy("Strategy HOLD", overlay = true)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

inTrade = strategy.position_size > 0
notInTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0
timeperiod = time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 01, 01)

active = rsi > 70

active_close = close < ma200

buy_price = ta.valuewhen(notInTrade, close[1] + close[1] * 4 / 100, 1)
stop_price = ta.valuewhen(notInTrade, close[1] - close[1] * 1 / 100, 1)

if timeperiod and active
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)

strategy.exit('long', profit = buy_price, stop = stop_price)

bgcolor(activate_long ? color.new(color.green, 50): na)
bgcolor(activate_buy ? color.new(color.purple, 50): na)
plot(buy_price, color = color.new(color.green, 0))
plot(stop_price, color = color.new(color.yellow, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculations seem off.

Also, `profit` argument of the `strategy.exit()` function expect the target in ticks.

If you want to have a TP at 4% and SL at 1%, use the following template.

```
tp_per = input.float(4.0, "TP %", minval=0.0, step=0.1) * 0.01
sl_per = input.float(1.0, "TP %", minval=0.0, step=0.1) * 0.01

tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_per)
sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_per)

if timeperiod and active
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit('long', limit=tp_price, stop=sl_price)
```